# Get returned values from table-valued function using SQLdatasource

Tags: asp.net, sql, user-defined-functions, sqldatasource

I made a simple Table-valued function that returns an Integer and a string. I've looked around but couldn't find anything about retrieving the returned data with a SQLdatasource.

I've tried using it the same way I used it for a scalar-valued function but then I keep getting the error:

> The request for procedure 'x' failed because 'x' is a table valued function object.

Is it even possible to call a table-valued function using a SQLdatasource?

Comment: What do you mean "using it the same way I used it for a scalar-valued function" - have you used a scalar-valied function in the SQLDatasource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use table-valued function this way, you need to make it a part of a query. E.g.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTableValuedFunc()
```

and use that query in your SQLdatasource